# VueJS router history mode with Traefik

Tags: traefik

I need to do rewrite a URL of my application like this: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

I'm using Traefik as a reverse proxy and Docker Compose.

Here is my raw configuration in Docker:

```yml
application:
    build: ./domain.app
    volumes:
      - ./domain.app/dist:/app
    networks:
      - net
    labels:
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:domain.me"
      - "traefik.port=8081"
      - "traefik.backend=domain.me"
      - "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http,https"
```

With that configuration:

https://domain.me **is working**

https://domain.me/anything **returns 404**

How can I fix this rewrite rule?

Comment: How are you serving your vue.js files? With Nginx, Apache or something else?

Comment: I'm serving those with node-static. `static --host-address 0.0.0.0 -p 8081 --gzip`

Comment: If this is for production I would highly recommend you to use a proper static file server like [nginx](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/) or [apache](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/). Then you can make the configuration changes as stated in your link: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations. If not you can implement you own http server as noted in the vue.js guide: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

Comment: The reason why you don't want to use Traefik for this is that traefik does not know which files are on your server. Traefik just relays the request to your server, which then determines if the file exists (200) or not (404). If you would configure traefik to rewrite every unknown route you would have to write a PathPrefixStripRegex which excludes every file that exists on your server and you really don't want to to that, even less updating it.

Comment: Allright, I think I'll drop Traefik in favour of Nginx like I made before! Thank you.

Comment: As long as you are only serving one app in one docker container that is perfectly fine. ;) You can leverage Traefik later when you want to use multiple docker containers, e.g. for load Balancing or serving different sub sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For vue.js router history mode you want to catch all Routes that do not point to a resource on the server and forward them to your `index.html`. For Example:

```
https://example.com                   --> /index.html
https://example.com/route/to/subsite  --> /index.html
```

But you still want to be able to access resources that are on the server. E.g.:

```
https://example.com/path/to/kitten.jpg --> /path/to/kitten.jpg not /index.html
```

In order to do that you have to find a Backend Server supporting Catch-All Fallback. You can use the ones noted in the [vue.js Guide](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#html5-history-mode) (Apache, Nginx, Node, IIS)

#### Why can't I use traefik for this?

As stated above you still want to be able to serve static resources. But traefik is just a router. It does only has access to the information of the request, not to the information of the server. But in order to decide if to serve the index.html or the static resource you must have access to the resources.

You could route all the traffic to the `index.html` using Traefik's `PathPrefixStripRegex:`but this would result in serving `index.html` for every request, even if you would have wanted `kitten.jpg`.